# Publishing Android app from Visual Studio: Google Play option disabled in Select Channel

Tags: android, visual-studio, google-play

[Visual Studio : Archive...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F6xt.png)

When I try to publish an Android app from Visual Studio (Archive Manager), the Google Play option is now grayed out (Ad Hoc still available). This worked earlier, but suddenly now isn't available. Any ideas why this happened and how I can fix it?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you fix it?

Comment: I figured it out, apk is not supported now, must me aab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, building an apk was the problem. When I change the package format to bundle (.aab file extension), google play button was enabled.

Comment: The button is available but publishing fails...

Comment: ist a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: If apk is not supported please add a reference