# Vs-2022 doesn't offer me the distribution channel Google Play as VS-2019 does

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

I have a Android project and made changes to the targeted Android version.

- I made a rebuild.
- I archived the build
- Now I wanted to start the distribution

But the current display shows a grayed out Google Play Distribution.

Using VS-2019 I can open the build from the archive and I can launch the distribution via `Google Play`. I successfully uploaded the App as an Alpha-Build.

What do I miss in VS-2022 (installed on the same machine)?

[image: current display shows a grayed out Google Play Distribution]

Comment: Does this help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72522773/publishing-android-app-from-visual-studio-google-play-option-disabled-in-select or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72885883/xamarin-android-distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Xamarin Android Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72885883/xamarin-android-distribution), you need to change the project properties -> Android Options and change the Android Package Format from apk to bundle.